# Django DetailView/ListView force XML rendering

Tags: xml, django, templates, django-templates, detailview

Is there a way to force DetailView/ListView to generate an XML file instead of an HTML?

I have already created an XML Template and it renders correctly, but the DetaiView doesn't allow to set the mimetype.

Any Ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DetailView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L145) inherits from [`SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin`](http://SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin) which inherits from [`TemplateResponseMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L92) which has a method [`render_to_response`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L99) in which the `mimemtype` can be set. So, something like

```
class MyView(DetailView):
    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).render_to_response(
            context,
            mimetype='application/xml',
            **response_kwargs)
```

should work

Comment: You code is perfect but throws an InvalidSyntax exception, mimetype should be placed before **response_kwargs in order to work..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use `content_type` attribute of you view

```
class MyView(DetailView):
    content_type = 'application/xml'
```

It provided by the [TemplateResponseMixin](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.base/TemplateResponseMixin/) since Django 1.5